# HTTP request hijkacked?

Tags: security, web-server, web-hosting

I've installed Tomcat 6 on my first, new VPS. I had added AccessLogValve to server.xml configuration Tomcat file.
In tomcat log I saw first this:

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [04/Mar/2011:23:43:12 +0000] "GET /w00tw00t.at.ISC.SANS.DFind:) HTTP/1.1" 400 - "-" "-"
```

and next day after this I went to this site (in internet browser) one of the requests in tomcat log was with the same IP like above record, but with User-Agent headers like mine (and session cookies - this I check by my webapp log).

This was repeated by 2 others IP: "GET /w00tw00t.at.ISC.SANS.DFind:)" in night and then hijacked one request in next day. How is it possible?
These 3 IPs were from 2 countries (2 of them is country where my VPS is located).

Answer (score 1):

This is just some kind of robot, which scans websites for vulnerability. I've seen it many times, and as long as your server properly configured and applying all security updates, this is not a problem.

If you still want to ban this robot take a loot to this article: http://blog.urlvoid.com/w00tw00t-at-isc-sans-dfind-web-scanner/

Answer (score 1):

[DLink vulnerability scanner](http://www.techsoar.com/w00tw00t-at-isc-sans-dfind-apache-logs/)

Comment: I know that this is scanner, but why next day I have successful request from this IP with my broweser headers and cookies?